# Selecting a default value for dependant dropdowns in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I need to pre select default values for two dependent dropdowns. So on page load the dropdowns should show something like "Automative" with "Two wheelers" selected.
(And not using selected attribute , the default values have to be loaded via $scope)
Below is the Plunkr link for the working dropdowns.

http://plnkr.co/edit/3Xrpb4jBziWNZE9JVfts?p=preview

```
<select class="home_search_select" name="d1" ng-model="selectedd1" ng-options="cat.category_id as cat.category_name for cat  in categorydata track by cat.category_id" id="d1">
   <option value="">Select Category</option>
</select>

<select class="home_search_select" name="d2" id="d2" ng-disabled="!selectedd1" ng-model="selectedd2" ng-options="subcat.ID as subcat.Name for subcat in ((categorydata|filter:{'category_id':selectedd1})[0].Subcategory) track by subcat.ID">
  <option class="home_search_select" value="">Select Sub Category</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value for selected1 as below

```
$scope.selectedd1= {
    "category_name": "Automotive",
    "category_id": "1",
    "Subcategory": [{
      "Name": "Two Wheeler",
      "ID": "1"
    }, {
      "Name": "Four Wheeler",
      "ID": "2"
    }, {
      "Name": "Heavy Moving Vehicles",
      "ID": "3"
    }, {
      "Name": "Automobile Related",
      "ID": "4"
    }]
  };
```

Modify the ng-options in the second dropdown

```
<select class="home_search_select" name="d2" id="d2"
    ng-disabled="!selectedd1" ng-model="selectedd2" 
    ng-options="subcat.ID as subcat.Name for subcat in selectedd1.Subcategory track by subcat.ID">
      <option class="home_search_select" value="">Select Sub Category</option>
 </select>
```

To listen the changes in the dropdown use `ng-change` directive

```
<select class="home_search_select" name="d1" 
ng-model="selectedd1" 
ng-change="homeChanged()"
ng-options="cat as cat.category_name for cat  in categorydata track by cat.category_id" id="d1">
  <option ng-value="">Select Category</option>
</select>
```

Note:`ng-options` is changed to contain the entire object

**[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/n0XJ6N2maPCyQ5a2vqfl?p=preview)**

Comment: Not working , Subcategory dropdown  is empty and on change also its broken. I need it to be working as the original.

Comment: just add `$scope.selectedd2 = $scope.selectedd1.Subcategory[0];` (instead of `$scope.selectedd2 = "1";`) to @Aravind's answer and it should work

Comment: @Andriy upvote if this works

Comment: Not working again...Kindly go through my query again.
I need two drop downs selected. Like "Automotive" with  "Two Wheeler" , or "Fashion" with ''Footwear" to appear initially.
And when i change again primary category, to anything it should populate subcategory with all matching values with "Select Subcategory" selected.

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: @Aravind, it does not work, It should work if you add to your code `$scope.selectedd2 = $scope.selectedd1.Subcategory[0];` Here is fixed plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/MfThyBndm6zRLxmtqe7p?p=preview

Comment: @Andriy Your solution worked ! thanks :) Could you post the comment as an answer , so that i can tick it.

Comment: thanks @Vish for you will to tick my answer, I think it is not possible now, since the question is marked as duplicate. I was and always am glad to help :)